# How to use a higher precision?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

Below is my code. If I set W to $10^{55}$, it breaks down and the result is wrong. What do I need to do to use W as large as $10^{200}$?

```
n = 15;
roots = Table[Sqrt[Prime[i]], {i, n}];
W = 10^45;
A = Table[0, {i, 1,  n + 1}, {j, 1, n + 1}];
A[[1, 1]] = 1; 
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, A[[1, i + 1]] = Round[W*roots[[i]]];];
For[i = 2, i <= n + 1, i++, A[[i, i]] = W; ];
b = LatticeReduce[A];
q = Abs[b[[1, 1]]]
```

**The error message is here:**

N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached while evaluating -28254824730949473896127703534134355343731647793777+19979178168491741166272766531031078657045486457686 Sqrt[2].

My version is V9, and my OS is windows 7.

Comment: What do you mean by breakdown?

Comment: @AnjanKumar  See the error message above.

Comment: In my system, I don't get any error message even for a W of $10^{100}$. You  may try increasing `$MaxExtraPrecision` like this
`Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100}, Round[W*#] & /@ roots]`

Comment: This appears to be a version-dependent problem, or we are missing some other information.  Please update your question to include the details of your platform.

Comment: Thanks for providing version information.  This might also be operating-system-dependent so it would be good to know if you are running this on Windows, OSX, or Linux.

Comment: Also note this is probably not the lattice you want. My guess is this variant will be more useful: `lat = Join[Map[List, Round[ww*Join[{1}, roots]]], 
   IdentityMatrix[n + 1], 2];
redlat = LatticeReduce[lat]`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work without error in v10.1 under Windows x64:

```
n = 15;
roots = Table[Sqrt[Prime[i]], {i, n}];
W = 10^200;
A = Table[0, {i, 1, n + 1}, {j, 1, n + 1}];
A[[1, 1]] = 1;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, A[[1, i + 1]] = Round[W*roots[[i]]];];
For[i = 2, i <= n + 1, i++, A[[i, i]] = W;];
b = LatticeReduce[A];
q = Abs[b[[1, 1]]]
```

> ```
> 485603484508849372516130007418504632602233691958877412852766931375138423098986536885\
> 657362770183762005362519092758826679723076465340151346365557521902058790127411374224\
> 440956272176411511
> ```

Comment: I see. My version is Version 9.

Comment: @S.Kohn Please include that information in the question itself.  You can [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/139919/edit) it at any time.